# save json info to model when button clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I wonder how I can achieve this :

I have a view that is fetching a string from a json api and display a string.

```
annonsrubrik = @results["platsannons"]["annons"]["annonsrubrik"]
```

Now I want to add a button/link that will take the "annonsrubrik" and saves it to my MyStream model.

I know how to save it to the model, but I wonder how to make the button save it and send a notice to my "notice:"

```
MyStream.create(:annonsrubrik => annonsrubrik)
```

This is what I have

JobstreamController

```
def annons
    @results = JSON.parse(open("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/#{params[:annonsid]}", "Accept" => "application/json", "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)

end
```

Jobstream view

```
<h1><%= @results["platsannons"]["annons"]["annonsrubrik"] %></h1>
```

MyStream controller is a scaffolded version and I have a table named "annonsrubrik" that is a string.

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve the results, Read more about action, routes, form and you will be able to solve it yourself.